3D Cursor not showing up when using preset viewpoint
I was working in Blender like normal, I mostly use the preset orthographic viewport, when all of a sudden, the 3D cursor just disappear. When goes back to he 3D view, it appears again, checking the viewport overlays shows that the 3D cursor is still enabled. There's no option in setting (at least as far as I know) to enable or disable it. Does anyone have a fix for this?



Did you try closing Blender and reopening it ? Indeed it's strange, 3D Cursor is enabled. Consider uploading your file with https://blend-exchange.com/.
